# Sequence of execution of Partial classes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, partial-classes

I have seen there are two partial classes of same class(FORM) in C# winforms.

> **1. Form1.cs**
>      **2. Form1.Designer.cs**

In which changes made in **Designer** effects the layout of form at same time **(without compilation)** but the changes made in **form1.cs (code file)** effects layout at runtime.

What is main difference in both files?
Which line makes difference in both files?
What is the sequence of execution of partial classes?

Comment: The accepted answer (and comments to it) are correct. But if you're asking about the `.designer.cs` file, it really shouldn't matter. **You aren't ever supposed to modify this file yourself.** It's handled internally by the Visual Studio designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial classes just allow the developer to split the class across multiple files.  When compiled it's as if the class existed in one file.

Comment: To clarify this answer, the "sequence of execution" is exactly the same as if the class existed in one file.  The compiler will read in both files and compose them together into one class.  So there is no "sequence of execution" per se.

Comment: how changes made in Designer effects the layout without compilation but the changes made in form1.cs (code file) effects layout at runtime?

Comment: @Javed: The Visual Studio designer *only* looks at the `.designer.cs` file that it generated. All your own code should just be in the normal .cs file.

Comment: Javed - I think you're looking at it backwards.  The designer file just represents the drag-and-drop changes you're making in Visual Studio at design time.  So yes, you can make changes in the form1.cs file and those don't get executed until runtime, but technically the form1.designer.cs file code isn't either.  You're using a Visual Studio designer that generates the code in the .designer.cs file for compilation.  You're looking at the .designer.cs file as if it has some dynamic super-powers that it doesn't - it's just synced with the WYSIWYG Winforms layout editor in VS.